# Heisenberg Uncertainty principle defined as $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq h$ versus $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \hbar/2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

At my university, in the during lectures and in the equation sheet for our exams, the formula for the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is stated as $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq h$, for example in one of my lecture notes, the following example is illustrated using this formula

[image]

However I know that in my textbook (*University Physics by Young and Freedman*) and pretty much universally the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is stated as $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$. Using this formula, we can see the example above is off by a factor of $4\pi$.

Is the formula, $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq h$, that my university uses a valid formula? If so is just a weaker version of $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$?

Comment: if you are asked to *estimate* something, you can ignore factors of $\pi$ or 2. In any case, the correct formula is $\Delta x\Delta p\ge\hbar/2$, as you can read it in the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)

Comment: I would suggest that, during an exam, use what is given regardless.  You might want to draw attention to the issue later ( e.g. in case of a printing error ), but do not trouble yourself during the actual exam.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69604/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle (HUP)is  encoded formally in the theory of quantum mechanics in  the [commutations relations](http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/quantrev/node18.html) of the operators defining the observables. There are a number of other observable variable pairs whose commutator is not zero

Commutators use $\hbar$ so it is the "correct" form in the calculations. On the other hand the HUP, when it was first proposed, was an extension of wave mechanics arguments and there a factor of $\pi$ or so was irrelevant. In the formal mathematics, one should use $\hbar$. See also the answer [here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153807/what-is-the-point-of-the-reduced-plancks-constant-hbar-h-bar-why-dont)