# Which is the true Planck's constant: $h$ or $ħ$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, physical-constants

My quantum mechanics book says that $ħ$ is the Planck's constant. The book uses ħ throughout and not one single use of $h$.

My statistical mechanics book says that $h$ is the [Planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) and doesn't use $ħ$ at all.

Now I know that one of the constant is the other scaled by $2\pi$. But one of them is the Planck's constant and the other is not. Which one of them is true Planck's constant?

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant)?

Comment: So my Quantum Mechanics book is wrong. Apparently $h$ is the true Planck constant. But $\hbar$ is is used everywhere and $h$ is used rarely.

Comment: What does "true Planck's constant" mean? $h$ is the proportionality constant between the energy of a photon and its "ordinary" frequency and $\hbar$ is the proportionality constant between the energy of a photon and its angular frequency. Which one of these is "true", and why?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153807/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the usual terminology we have
\begin{align}
h &&&\text{Planck's constant} \\
\hbar &= \frac{h}{2\pi} &&\text{reduced Planck's constant}
\end{align}

The significance of $2\pi$ here is the ratio between a full circle and a radian, because the energy of a photon is
$$ E = hf = \hbar \omega \;,$$
where $f$ is the cyclic frequency of the light and $\omega = 2 \pi f$ is its angular frequency. Both are common because—by long tradition—the frequency and wavelength of waves are generally measured with respect to a full cycle, but mathematical expressions involving waves may be written down more compactly in terms of angular (radian-based) quantities such as the angular frequency and the wavenumber ($k = 2\pi/\lambda$).

Comment: But it is not uncommon to see, as did the OP, the word "reduced" left off the description of $\hbar$. Reader beware.

Comment: Well, yes. And I do it myself when there is only one of the symbols involved in the discussion, but I encourage people to be specific where there is the possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It is $h$.
$\hbar$ is $\frac{h}{2π}$.

Planck constant $h$
reduced constant $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [original: 10.1002/andp.19013090310](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqpNuEyoPUAhWGb1AKHaD8B8EQFggzMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fonlinelibrary.wiley.com%2Fdoi%2F10.1002%2Fandp.19013090310%2Fabstract&usg=AFQjCNHnH_zGniPOlaqkBJ01G6TpHhXzHw&sig2=AZcPSRGjD00xOOY5TfeHoA). Planck uses $h$ has it is about the relation of frequency and energy.